# array_count_values no working

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

i have this array called $emp

```
array(4) {
 [0]=> array(1) {
    ["hadir"]=> string(1) "0" } 
 [1]=> array(1) { 
    ["hadir"]=> string(1) "0" } 
 [2]=> array(1) { 
    ["hadir"]=> string(1) "1" } 
 [3]=> array(1) { 
    ["hadir"]=> string(1) "2" } 
}
```

how to get result like

> hadir 0 = 2 
>   hadir 1 = 1
>   hadir 2 = 1

i try like this

```
$counts = array_count_values($emp);

var_dump($counts['0']);
```

but show me error " array_count_values(): Can only count STRING and INTEGER values!"

Comment: Please search StackOverflow for a short while before posting a new question.

Answer (score 0):

`array_count_values` is only for 1-dimensional arrays. You can use `array_column()` to get the `hadir` values of each element:

```
$counts = array_count_values(array_column($emp, "hadir"))
```

Comment: still get error message "array_column() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given"

Comment: parameters are reversed, @Barmar  (duplicate question anyhow)